# c# add using declaration for namespace to all classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to add a using declaration to a namespace globally?

For example, I want all of my classes under the "MyApp.Models" namespace to include the namespace System.Linq.Dynamic.

In asp.net you can do this for view by adding the namespace in the web.config.  Is there a way to do this for class files as well?

Comment: FYI - I've used the web.config mechansim too but it breaks if you use code-behind. You're back to listing them for each class!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  It is not possible to add a global `using` declaration to a C# project.  You must specify the complete set of `using` in each .cs file

Comment: Although I fear it to be true, I don't want this to be the correct answer!

Comment: @Victor unfortunately what i said is true :(.  VB.Net supports the notion of project level imports but C# doesn't.

Comment: and what if all classes were partial to one with defined using references?

Comment: @sasjaq partial classes still have to declare separate `using` in every .cs file they are defined in

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do what you want with obvious functionality but you could create a template that you generate your classes from and do that by namespace, the templates could include the using and this would give you the desired effect.

You could do this with basic T4 templates or something like resharper also has this functionality.

However it is a bit pointless, lots of productivity tools will bring in the using statements you need given code you write, resharper and others do this, so it is not neccessary to have a template that does this as you may end up in each namespace not using the declaration then find yourself having to delete it !

Theres not really an issue with having using statements that are unused by the way its just messy.

Ooh just in case you aren't sure what t4 templating is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) is a quick link

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible out of the box, but you could certainly automate with a Visual Studio plugin or a plugin for a tool like Code Rush.

Comment: You can also create/edit visual studio templates so that the .cs files you create already have this (or other) using statements at the top if you almost always want them there.

Comment: this can be done using t4 but code rush or resharper are a better bet.